# Mail server (Win2003) can't receive emails, why?

Tags: windows-server-2003, email-server, pop3

Everything is fine when checking with smtdiag.exe

Everything works fine with telnet.

Tried from outside, connect to mail server everything works fine also - this means no ports are blocked.

The problem is that mail server is unable to recieve any email messages... Tried from yahoo.com, from gmail.com send some test emails but these emails don't arrive to mail server, there is no new messages when checking with telnet "list"...

Emails are just disappearing somewhere... How to check what's wrong?

Comment: I think you should tell us what mail server software you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If all your services are set up correctly, chances are that the problem is to do with mail getting to your system in the first place.  Are your domain's MX records for your domain set up to point to your server?  You mentioned that you'd tested using telnet; did you actually send a mail through telnet and see it arrive?  And if so, what happens when you try the same thing from a remote location?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to deliver a message via telnet to the server. If it accepts the email and you still don't see it then the queues may be misconfigured. If gmail can't reach the server you will usually receive a undeliverable notice in that gmail inbox.

Telnet SMTP walk through:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119

Check the event viewer log files for any service errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

ok found some new things.. the problem is that all email arrive to server, but all these messages goes to Drop folder.. nothing in system logs (event viewer), what could be a problem? tried to google about this but didn't find smth usefull...

Comment: OK, we really do need to know what mail server you're using now - IIS?  Sendmail? Postfix?